# store in table, Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a problem to store data in a table. And after hours I still couldnt figure out, what the problem is. I would be so happy for some help!

WishlistController.php:

```
public function store($book_id)
    {
        $user_id=Auth::id();
        $wishlist=new Wishlist;
        $wishlist->book_id=$book_id;
        $wishlist->user_id= $user_id;
        $wishlist->save();
        return redirect()->route('wishlistCRUD.show' , $book_id->id)
            ->with('success', 'Buch gewünscht');
```

The Model:

```
class Wishlist extends Model
{
    public $table = 'wishlist';
    public $fillable = ['book_id','user_id',];
```

the view.blade:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'wishlistCRUD.store', 'method'=>'POST')) !!}
  <form action="someaction" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="{{$book->id}}"/>
  </form>    
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('wishlistCRUD.store',$book->id) }}">wünschen</a>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

the Route:

```
Route::post('wishlistCRUD.store', 'WishlistController@store');
```

When I check the table, nothing new is added.
Its frustrating :-(

Comment: No errors are given to you?

Comment: If you `dd($book_id);`, what does it print?

Comment: @Laerte where you want me to put dd($book_id); ?

Comment: Before `$user_id=Auth::id();`

Comment: where is it supposed to print something? i didnt notice any changes.

Comment: If it is printing nothing, this function is never called. This is probably the root of the problem

Comment: You should change `<a>` anchor for a send button. And add {book_id} in your route. This should do the trick

Comment: do you mean a submit-button? send he doesnt know. how should i add {book_id} in the route?

Comment: Take a look at my answer and check if it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this. In your Controller, you don't need $book_id as a parameter because you can get it from the $request:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $book_id = $request->book_id;

    $wishlist = new Wishlist;
    $wishlist->book_id = $book_id;
    $wishlist->user_id = $user_id;
    $wishlist->save();

    return redirect()->route('wishlistCRUD.show' , $book_id)
            ->with('success', 'Buch gewünscht');
}
```

Don't forget to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

And then in your blade, you don't need to set a route in an anchor, because it is already defined in the form. And you don't need two forms, because `Form::open` already does that:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'wishlistCRUD.store', 'method'=>'POST')) !!}
  {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="{{$book->id}}"/>
  {!! Form::submit('wünschen') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This should work.

Comment: Oh my god! It worked! You safed me so many worries! Thank you :-D

Answer (score 1):

Just change post to get in this line:

```
    Route::post('wishlistCRUD.store', 'wishlistCRUD@store');
```

Comment: that is sadly not working. I only get the redirect to wishlistCRUD.show

Answer (score 0):

In blade, change the 
`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('wishlistCRUD.store',$book->id) }}">wünschen</a>`

to a `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">wünschen</button>`

Delete the tag `form`, it's not necesary. You declared it with the {!! form:open... !!}

You are trying to access to `route('wishlistCRUD.store',$book->id)` by GET with the `<a></a>`

Try this:
the view.blade:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'wishlistCRUD/store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!} 
    <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="{{$book->id}}"/> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">wünschen</button> 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

the Route:

```
Route::post('wishlistCRUD/store', 'WishlistController@store');
```

Comment: If I change to a button. and then keep Route::post('wishlistCRUD.store', 'WishlistController@store'); the button does nothing.

Comment: Did you delet the tag <form> ? 
i edited the answer :D

Comment: Now I also deleted the <form>tags but that also didnt help :'-(

Comment: I think the problem is in the blade and controller.

Comment: blade and route*

Answer (score 0):

You have created `POST` method in your web.php for adding book to wish list, in your blade template you need to submit hidden form on click of link.

in your web.php

```
Route::get('wishlistCRUD/book/{book_id}','WishlistController@get_book_by_id')->name('get_book_by_id');

    Route::post('wishlistCRUD.store', 'WishlistController@store')->name('store');
```

In your blade template

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('addToWishlist').submit();">wünschen</a>

<form style="display:none" id="addToWishlist" method="POST" action="{{ route('store')}}">{{csrf_field()}} <input type="hidden" name="bookid" value="{{$book->id}}" /> </form>
```

in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $bookID= $request->input('bookid');
        $wishlist=new Wishlist();
        $wishlist->book_id= $bookID
        $wishlist->user_id= Auth::user()->id;
        $wishlist->save();
        return redirect()->route('get_book_by_id', ['book_id' => $bookID]);
}


public function get_book_by_id(Request $request,$book_id){
     // find book by ID;

     $book=Book::find($book_id);

     // book found 
     if($book){

       return view('book')->with('book',$book);

     }else{

      // book not found , redirect to 404 page or home page
       return redirect('/');
     }
}
```